# POSIX File Error - Extraneous double quotes?

Tags: macos, applescript

This applescript works

```
set myFile to (POSIX path "/Users/fred/Documents/data.dat")
```

This applescript doesn't work

```
set myFileName to "/Users/fred/Documents/data.dat"
set myFile to (POSIX path myFileName)
```

It fails with the error

```
    get POSIX file "/Users/fred/Documents/data.dat"
    --> error number -1728
Result:
error "iTunes got an error: Can’t get POSIX file \"/Users/fred/Documents/data.dat\"." number -1728 from file "Macintosh HD:Users:drew:Desktop:Music:DIY:DIY-01.mp3"
```

It looks as if when using the variable, POSIX path is including the double quotes as explicit characters in the file name.  What am I doing wrong?

The script below reproduces the problem.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set newFileName to "/Users"
    set newFile to POSIX file newFileName
end tell
```

Thanks

Comment: ... so why not just remove them?

Comment: ...because the `set myFileName to "/Users/fred/Documents/data.dat"`  needs them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK - I've found out what I should be doing.

The script below works - you just need to coerce the variable rather than pass it to `POSIX file`

```
tell application "Finder"
    set newFileName to "/Users"
    set newFile to (newFileName as POSIX file)
end tell
```

Result...

```
file "Macintosh HD:Users"
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

"/Users/fred/Documents/data.dat" Is already a posix path

```
tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file "/Users/fred/Documents/data.dat"
```

or

```
tell application "System Events" to open "/Users/fred/Documents/data.dat"
```

Here is an example for iTunes:

```
tell application "Finder" to set myFile to (POSIX file "/Users/John/Desktop/08 5150.mp3")
tell application "iTunes" to set resultTrack to add myFile to playlist "test"
```

Comment: If I use a literal string as an argument (as you have suggested in your answer), it works.  The problem I am having is that when I try and use a variable set to the name of the path, `POSIX file` fails.

Comment: I'm going to be adding a track - but it's not relevant to this question because it works fine if I set the file name using a literal - it doesn't get as far as adding the track when I use a variable - it bombs out trying to obtain the file reference.

Comment: I've created an absolute bare minimum script that reproduces the problem.  I'll edit the question to include it...

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of how to add a file to a playlist.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the question I asked.  Just try running the simple `tell Finder` script I have appended to the original question and tell me if it works for you or not.